# Gretty, Spring MVC and hot deployment

Tags: java, gradle, deployment, gretty

I am learning Spring MVC and trying to use it together with Gradle and Gretty plugin. I have successfully created a "Hello World" project, however I am not able to use hot deployment with Gretty, despite setting the `managedClassReload=true`. I run the application by using `appRun` gretty task from IntelliJ. My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

group = 'lukeg'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'lukeg.LearnApplication'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:+')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.17.RELEASE')
    compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.11")
    compile('org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'tomcat9'
    //reloadOnClassChange=true
    managedClassReload=true
    loggingLevel='DEBUG'
}
```

It does not matter whether I use `tomcat9` or `jetty9` for servlet container: the logs do not show that the changes to source files in project are detected by Gretty.

Interesingly enough, when I comment out the `managedClassReload=true` line and uncomment `reloadOnClassChange=true` the changes to source files are detected and the project is automatically reloaded.

What can be the cause for gretty's hot deployment not working? Does springloaded not work together with Spring MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to depend on the plugin script you are gathering from github since `org.gretty` is available in the official [Gradle plugin repository](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty) for some time already:

```
plugins {
  id "org.gretty" version "2.1.0"
}
```

Since you are running your app inplace using [appRun](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/appRun-task.html), your changes will not be reloaded.
You have to run you application as war, using [appRunWar](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/appRunWar-task.html).

This is not mentioned in the documentation. But in the Gretty source code.
You can check the Gretty [code](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/936fcb7b9d5ccfb78abf6a43e85cb684bc24f372/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/scanner/BaseScannerManager.groovy#L185) which causing your issue in the `BaseScannerManager`:

```
if(wconfig.reloadOnClassChange) 
{
    if(managedClassReload) 
    {
        if(wconfig.inplace) // <-- your problem, you are running inplace
        {
            log.info 'file {} is in managed output of {}, servlet-container will not be restarted', f, wconfig.projectPath
        }
        else 
        {
            log.info 'file {} is in output of {}, but it runs as WAR, servlet-container will be restarted', f, wconfig.projectPath
            webAppConfigsToRestart.add(wconfig)
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
       log.info 'file {} is in output of {}, servlet-container will be restarted', f, wconfig.projectPath
       webAppConfigsToRestart.add(wconfig)
    }
}
```